# Sustitucion modo bucle notepad++

Tags: notepad++

estaba usando notepad++ y tengo lo siguiente en el documento, repetido muchas veces

```
<div class="cuenta">
```

Quería saber si había alguna expresión para que los reemplazara todos los `<div class="cuenta">` por `<div class="cuenta1"> <div class="cuenta2"> ... <div class="cuentaN">`, es decir que vaya iterando.

Comment: Podemos ver un trozo del fuente real?

Comment: Si sin problemas sería

...Algo no interesante....
<div class="cuenta">
...Algo no interesante....
</div>
<div class="cuenta">
...Algo no interesante....
</div>
<div class="cuenta">
...Algo no interesante....
</div>
<div class="cuenta">
...Algo no interesante....
</div>
<div class="cuenta">
...Algo no interesante....
</div>
<div class="cuenta">
...Algo no interesante....
</div>

Comment: Muy real no parece :-)

Comment: Necesitaría una copia real, incluyendo lo que hay en "algo no interesante" y preservando los saltos de línea si los hubiera.... un trozo real del código.